# How to open the link of RSS link XML Element in a new window?

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I am working on RSS. In that I am creating the title by giving link also for it. When we click on that link it opens it in same window.. but i want that to open in new window. Can anyone tell me how to get that??

```
<link>http://www.google.com</link>
```

Comment: The RSS concept does not have a model for what a *Window* is. Can you please give an example where you (the user) would see that link and how would it look like if clicked? Both like it does right now (causing you the issue) *and* how you want it to be.

Comment: edited please check it out

Answer (score 1):

RSS just provides data. Interactivity is not possible here. So html tags will not work here. But fortunately many RSS reader renders HTML tags inside it. For those RSS readers you can pass HTML tags as *character data*. Like this,

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
    Read <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">more</a>
]]>
</description>
```

This will render as following on HTML supported RSS readers.

> Read [more](http://stackoverflow.com)

But I am not sure whether it'll work on `<link>`. Because `<link>` should contain only URL. Arbitrary phrase is not allowed here.

Comment: The `description` element is not the `link` element. How is this an answer?

Comment: yes, in link tag how we need to add target _blank?

Comment: @VinothBabu: You already tried that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14560369/367456

Comment: @hakre the answer is in the first paragraph.

Comment: @shilpu: ur ri8. but i need to set it like setTitle() setLink() :(

Comment: @VinothBabu dont modify the RSS. Parse it render HTML using the information found in RSS.

Comment: @shilpu: i am creating rss file and opening in browser. i am not parsing to see it.

Comment: Then its completely fine. You dont have to make a clickable link.  Browsers are not RSS reader btw. Try open it with a news reader

Comment: how to open it with news reader?

Comment: @shilpu:actually we give the links to others and they will open it. so how can i do it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23500/discussion-between-vinoth-babu-and-shiplu-mokadd-im)

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: well, on a second read probably. Because it says you can't use HTML and then you suggest to use HTML. I mean, *I* understand it, however it might be a bit shady.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the RSS reader that the user is using. Obviously in a browser you'd add `target="_blank"` to an `<a>` tag, but that's a convention that browsers have naturally adopted over time. There's no guarantee that `target="_blank"` will work for all or even any readers, but you could try it.

The fact is that you shouldn't force this behaviour for the user anyway - it is really up to them how they handle their tabs/windows. If I want to open a link in a new tab or window I will explicitly do so using the browser's commands.

Answer (score 0):

The `<channel>`'s `<link>` element contains an URL (in RSS 2.0) that is:

> The URL to the HTML website corresponding to the channel.

Compare with [the specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html).

What can be done with such a link/URL is out of scope of the RSS specification. Therefore no advice can be given to open (or not open) that link in the same window.

Also you have not specified what the window is you talk about. I assume it's part of a software that has a Graphical User Interface (GUI) that displays the link from the RSS feed for informational purposes.

So that software (the software you didn't specify) is in control to open the link in (the same or) a new window. You can not control that with the RSS feed but with the software.

Which software are you using to display the RSS feed?

Answer (score -1):

replace your code from this, give target as a blank

```
<link target ="_blank">http://www.google.com</link>
```

Comment: Why would it work. Its RSS, Its not HTML.

Comment: yes in RSS how we need to do is the ques not in html

Comment: follow this http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/use-links

Comment: Where is target attribute on your link?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im i already define this in my answer. :)